# Two python/pygame programs to run in the same window

Tags: python, pygame

I want to call a python/pygame program from inside another. I do this with the os.startfile(minigame1) command. But when the program launches it first runs a python command line window and then opens the minigame in a seperate window. How can I make both programs share the same pygame window? Thank you in advance

Comment: Majorly refactor your code. As far as I am aware, this is not possible. Try rewriting the minigame inside the main program.

Comment: Im pretty sure you cant do that just launching a program ... you can use the `os.exec` methods to replace the current program with the new one ... but I dont think thats what you are trying to do

Comment: I need to run the mini program in the same window opened by the master program and then on exit return to where i left off in the master program. Now it does that but in two windows. How to do it in 1?

Answer (score 0):

If it is at all possible for two instances of a Pygame program to share a common display, then try using `pygame.display.get_surface()` to get the display surface- this will return `None` if the display isn't already initialized.

Another issue you will have to overcome in your project is the fact that calling `pygame.event.get()` (or a similar method) in one program will hide it from the other, so you will have to share the `pygame.event.Event`s between the two programs.

This would only work if you can get the two programs to share the same window though; if Pygame's written so that separate Python processes will have separate Pygame windows, then I doubt you'll be able to get around that without changing up the Pygame source.

Comment: Your suggestion worked! Only thing is I need to return back to where I left off in the earlier program. Let's me see how to figure that out. Thank You very much SimonT.   Joran Beasley and  sweeneyrod thank you for your response.